# Error al sumar 2 objetos con operador "+"

Tags: c++

Estoy tratando de sumar 2 objetos de tipo racional y que el resultado me lo retorne en un tercer objeto y guardarlo en un puntero en el main pero me da el siguiente error y me subraya el objeto r2:

```
 main.cpp:13:20: error: cannot convert 'Racional' to 'Racional*' in 
 initialization
 Racional *R=r1+r2;
```

no me puedo dar cuenta que es,les pego el codigo si alguien se puede dar cuenta del error me avisa

```
class Racional{
    private:

    int a;
    int b;

    public:

    Racional(int,int);
    ~Racional();
    Racional operator+(Racional&);
};

Racional& Racional::operator+(Racional R2){
    int aR1=this->a;
    int bR1=this->b;

    int aR2=R2.a;
    int bR2=R2.b;

    int aR3=0;
    int bR3=0;

    aR3=(aR1*bR2)+(bR2*aR2);
    bR3=(bR1*bR2);

    return *(new Racional(aR3,bR3));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Racional r1(3,5);
    Racional r2(6,5);

    Racional *R=r1+r2;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Estoy tratando de sumar 2 objetos de tipo racional.

No es verdad, el error que compartes dice otra cosa:

> ```
> error: cannot convert 'Racional' to 'Racional*'
> ```

Lo traduzco para mayor claridad:

> ```
> error: no se puede convetir 'Racional' en 'Racional*'
> ```

Los tipos con los que estás trabajando son `Racional` por un lado y `Racional*` (puntero a `Racional`) por otro. Un puntero a tipo no es el tipo de la misma manera que una matricula de coche, aunque nos identifique un coche, no es un coche.

---

El problema se centra en tu implementación del operador suma:

```
Racional& Racional::operator+(Racional R2){
    int aR1=this->a;
    int bR1=this->b;

    int aR2=R2.a;
    int bR2=R2.b;

    int aR3=0;
    int bR3=0;

    aR3=(aR1*bR2)+(bR2*aR2);
    bR3=(bR1*bR2);

    return *(new Racional(aR3,bR3));
}
```

Es una implementación muy incorrecta muy peligrosa y más complicada de lo necesario, enumerando los problemas de mayor a menor:

1. Devuelves el contenido de un puntero a memoria dinámica como si fuese memoria automática, perdiendo rastro del puntero y provocando fugas de memoria:

   ```
   Racional{1,2} + Racional{3,4}; // Esto ya es una fuga de memoria!
   ```
2. El operador debe devolver una instancia, no una referencia:

   ```
   Racional Racional::operator+( ... )
   ~~~~~~~~ <--- Instancia
   ```
3. El operador no debe modificar el objeto sobre el que se opera, debería ser constante por la derecha:

   ```
   Racional Racional::operator+( ... ) const
                        Constante ---> ~~~~~
   ```
4. El operador no debe modificar el objeto recibido, ni copiarlo el parámetro debe ser una referencia constante:

   ```
   Racional Racional::operator+(const Racional &) const
      Referencia constante ---> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ```
5. No coincide la declaración del operador en la clase `Racional` con su definición fuera de la misma.

   ```
   // En la clase devuelve instancia recibe referencia
   class Racional{
       Racional operator+(Racional&);
   };
   // Fuera de la clase devuelve referencia recibe instancia
   Racional& Racional::operator+(Racional R2){
   ```
6. No necesitas el puntero `this` para referirte a datos del objeto en el que estás:

   ```
   // Esto:
   int aR1=this->a;
   int bR1=this->b;
   // Es lo mismo que esto:
   int aR1=a;
   int bR1=b;
   ```
7. Añadir variables temporales para acceder a datos que ya son accesibles, complica el código y hace que sea más difícil de seguir y entender. Todo el operador que has redactado funciona de la misma manera así (ten en cuenta que la implementación es incorrecta, como menciono en el punto 1):

   ```
   Racional& Racional::operator+(Racional R2){
       return *(new Racional((a*R2.b)+(R2.b*R2.a),(b*R2.b)));
   }
   ```

En definitiva, para solucionar los puntos anteriores, tu operador de suma debería tener este aspecto:

```
Racional {
    Racional operator+(const Racional &) const;
//  ~~~~~~~~           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ~~~~~ <--- constante por la derecha
//  instancia       referencia constante  
};

Racional Racional::operator +(const Racional &r) const {
    return {a * r.b + r.b * r.a, b * r.b};
}
```

Y tu `main` debería parecerse a:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Racional r1(3,5);
    Racional r2(6,5);

    Racional R=r1+r2; // Sin puntero.
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

El error es claro como el agua. Te está diciendo que no sabe cómo convertir un objeto de tipo `Racional` en un puntero de tipo `Racional`. Así vemos como el operador suma devuelve una referencia:

```
   Racional& Racional::operator+(Racional R2)
// ~~~~~~~~~ Referencia
```

Mientras que tu código intenta almacenar esa referencia en un puntero:

```
Racional *R = r1+r2;
//       ~~ Puntero
```

No hay ninguna razón para que `R` sea un puntero, así que salvo que en el ejercicio te lo estén pidiendo de forma expresa, lo mejor es usar objetos por valor:

```
Racional Racional::operator+(Racional R2){ // <<--- ya no devuelve una referencia
    int aR1=this->a;
    int bR1=this->b;

    int aR2=R2.a;
    int bR2=R2.b;

    int aR3=0;
    int bR3=0;

    aR3=(aR1*bR2)+(bR2*aR2);
    bR3=(bR1*bR2);

    return Racional(aR3,bR3); // <<--- no usamos memoria dinámica
}

// ...

Racional R = r1 + r2;
```